# React binding issue with fetch wrapper

Tags: reactjs

New react user here. I am trying to create a custom wrapper for the `fetch()` method:

```
/**
 * Custom fetch() wrapper
 *
 * @param options {object} - options for request
 *
 **/

export const Ajax = (options) => {

    const defaultOptions={
        url:"",
        method:"get",
        onSuccess:function(json){
            console.log("Default success handler. ", json)
        },
        onError:function(error){
            console.log("Default error handler", error);
        },
        onStart:function(){

        },
        onComplete:function(){

        }
    };

    const mergedOptions = {...defaultOptions, ...options};
    mergedOptions.onStart();

    return () => fetch(mergedOptions.url, {
        credentials: 'include'
    })
        .then((response) =>  {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw response;
            }
            return response;
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            mergedOptions.onSuccess(responseJson);
            mergedOptions.onComplete();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            mergedOptions.onError(error);
            mergedOptions.onComplete();
        });
};

export default Ajax;
```

I am calling it like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Ajax from '../../functions/Ajax.jsx';

class SinglePageContainer extends Component{


    fetchData(){
        let url="/data-url";

        return Ajax({
            url:url,
            onStart:function(){
                this.setState({loading:true});
            },
            onComplete:function(){
                this.setState({loading:false});
            },
            onSuccess:function(json){
                this.setState({ajaxData:json.data});
            }

        }).bind(this);


    }

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading:true,
            error:false
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }
}

export default SinglePageContainer;
```

When running this, I get the error `this.setState is not a function for Object.onStart()`.

So `onStart()` is being called but the `SinglePageContainer` is not binding. How can I bind it to the parameter object? I used `Ajax({options}).bind(this);` but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call bind for `onStart`, `onComplete`, `onSuccess` functions, something like this :

```
fetchData(){
    let url="/data-url";

    return Ajax({
        url:url,
        onStart:function(){
            this.setState({loading:true});
        }.bind(this),
        onComplete:function(){
            this.setState({loading:false});
        }.bind(this),
        onSuccess:function(json){
            this.setState({ajaxData:json.data});
        }.bind(this)
    });
}
```

or you can use `Arrow functions`:

```
 fetchData(){
    let url="/data-url";

    return Ajax({
        url: url,
        onStart: () => {
            this.setState({ loading:true });
        },
        onComplete: () => {
            this.setState({ loading:false });
        },
        onSuccess: (json) => {
            this.setState({ ajaxData:json.data });
        }
    });
}
```

What you are doing now is that you are binding `this` inside your fetch wrapper, which has no impact on the object that you are passing to this function.

Comment: Is using the `arrow ()=>` function always the same as `.bind(this)` at the end?

Comment: Not the same. In addition to the non-binding of `this`, `arrow functions` have other features such as: No binding of arguments (Arrow functions do not have their own arguments object), Use of the new operator (Arrow functions cannot be used as constructors), and many others. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)